# I can't run the jar file after clean & build?

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-warnings

When I try to compile my NetBeans project I get a  `Build successful` message.

But I try to clean and build I get this message:

```
Note: C:\Rech\src\view\class.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

After this, I try to run the JAR file but the `javaw.exe` process has no response

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you do not understand? You use deprecated API, that is no longer considered safe/updated/useful and the compiler simply tells you that you should use newer API (and each time some Java API is deprecated, there is new one that takes its functionality). And you always listen to compiler, because compiler is always right. If you recompile with -Xlint:deprecation argument, you can see which APIs are deprecated and replace them.